# Access ProcessInstance records?

Tags: approval-process

I am trying to access any `ProcessIntance` records in my org. I'm able to see the object in a report type, but I'd like to be able to find this object in the UI. What changes could I make to expose this object type?

Answer (score 3):

ProcessInstance object is available via SOAP API only.You can not view the object in your application but with the help of Workbench or Data Loader you can query on the object.

- ProccessInstance is parent of ProcessInstanceSteps and
     ProcessInstanceWorkItem. ProcessInstanceSteps stores the steps
     followed by approvers  e.g. accept, reject or reassign etc all these saved 
     in ProcessInstanceSteps. Information like OriginalactorId, (parent)
     processInstanceId etc are saved in ProcessInstanceWorkItem. It
     mostly used for pending approvals.

If you want to query on ProcessInstance Object,you can query like this:

```
SELECT CompletedDate,CreatedById,CreatedDate,ElapsedTimeInDays,ElapsedTimeInHours,ElapsedTimeInMinutes,Id,IsDeleted,LastActorId,LastModifiedById,LastModifiedDate,ProcessDefinitionId,Status,SubmittedById,SystemModstamp,TargetObjectId FROM ProcessInstance
```

Check the below link for more details:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_erd_process.htm

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_processinstance.htm